# Почему символ \b (BACKSPACE) некорректно работает на C вместе с \b\n?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("Example.\b \n"); /* Example */
    printf("Example.\b\n"); /* Example. */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что такое "некорректно" и как должно быть "корректно"?

Comment: Если использовать \b и \n вместе, то \b перестаёт "действовать".

Comment: Именно такой результат и получается при консольном выводе. Не вижу ничего  "некорректного". С чего вы взяли, что `\b` перестал действовать? В чем выражается это "переставание"?

Comment: А почему тогда символ \b не действует? Это и есть некорректность! Это сравнимо с "Example.\n" == "Example.\b\n"!

Comment: Сколько можно повторять один и тот же вопрос: где вы тут увидели "не действует"??? Откуда вы пришли к такому выводу?

Comment: Почему символ \b вместе с \n НЕ УДАЛЯЕТ ТОЧКУ? Вы можете мне ответить?

Comment: Символ `\b` никогда ничего не удаляет и не должен удалять. Символ `\b` вызывает перемещение текущей позиции ("курсора") на один шаг назад. Все. Больше символ `\b` ничего не делает.

Comment: Спасибо. Но почему и в чём причина?

Comment: Потому что так сказано в спецификации языка, и так всегда было задолго до нее. В этом заключается и всегда заключалось назначение символа `\b` - перемещать курсор на один шаг назад. Ваш вопрос звучит как "почему в сутках 24 часа". Так исторически сложилось.

Comment: Если я после символа \b сделаю любой другой символ (кроме \n) или вообще его не сделаю, то вывод в консоль будет без точки. Почему \n влияет на вывод?

Comment: Это исторический баг и фикс?

Comment: Потому что вы переместили курсор назад при помощи `\b`, а потом *затерли* вашу точку следующим печатным символом (пробелом, например). Символ `\n`  - это непечатный символ, он просто переводит курсор на следующую строку и ничего не затирает. Исчезновение вашей точки не имеет никакого отношения к `\b`. Исчезновение точки зависит от того, что вы сами сделаете *после* `\b`.

Comment: О каком "баге" вы говорите - не ясно. Символ `\b` всегда был командой перевода курсора на один символ назад, еще со времен механических печатных машинок. Никаких багов тут нет.

Comment: @AnT В последних комментариях вы хорошо объяснили, что именно происходит. Это достойно переноса в ответ.

Comment: @AnT дайте ответ страждущему :) в *ответе*,  можно с ссылкой на документуию `escape char`, которую явно не читает сейчас никто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выводе на консоль `\b` просто перемещает курсор влево на одну позицию. Последующий вывод производится в неё. А перевод строки тоже просто перемещает позицию курсора, соответственно поверх "затираемого" символа ничего не выводится.

Также замечу, что при выводе в файл (вместо консоли) все символы будут выводиться как есть и никакого затирания не будет ни в каком случае.

Answer (score 2):

Статья в [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B) для управляющего символа **\b** говорит:

> `\b` Перемещает позицию печати на один символ назад. На принтерах
>   может использоваться для наложения одного символа на другой, например
>   `a BS ^ = â`. При вводе с терминала иногда используется для стирания
>   предшествующего символа («забой»).

Так как терминалы были разработаны с оглядкой на принтеры (в старых бездисплейных компьютерах они бумажными принтерами и были), символ **\b** работает вот так. Сегодня это менее актуально, так как большинство терминатов перерисуют символ целиком, однако это всё ещё может иметь смысл при использовании дисплеев которые позволяют управлять каждым пикселем индивидуально.

"Ошибка" не в сочетании **\b\n**, а в пробеле после **\b**, который затирает точку.

К примеру, если выполнить

```
printf("Exampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");
```

вывод будет выглядеть примерно вот так

```
Exampleeeeeeeeeeeeeedbotan@ubuntu:~/proj/c/sandbox$^Ceeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.
```

что указывает на то, что **\b** ничего не затирает.